# Django models : Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Students'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to filter objects based on a foreign key and I'm getting that error. When I use int( id of categories) the code below works. How can I make it work for strings?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class dash(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    card_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="dash_pics/")
    embed_tag=models.TextField()
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def students(request):
    stu_dashboards = models.dash.objects.filter(category='Students')
    return render(request,'dashboards/students.html',{'dashboards':stu_dashboards})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not filter with `category='Students'`, since `category` is a `ForeignKey` to the `Category` model.

You can however filter on the `category_name`, with:

```
def students(request):
    stu_dashboards = models.dash.objects.filter(category__category_name='Students')
    return render(request,'dashboards/students.html',{'dashboards':stu_dashboards})
```

---

> **Note**: Normally model fields have no prefix with the name of the model. This makes
> queries longer to read, and often want uses inheritance of (abstract) models to
> inherit fields, so using a prefix would make it less reusable. Therefore it
> might be better to rename your field <s>`category_name`</s> to `name`.

Comment: thanks it works! is it convention to use 2 underscores while doing this sort of a thing?

Comment: @shardul: the double underscores are used to look "through" a relation (like a foreign key). See for example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/